# mySQL, Select January, February, and also November. each year

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in need to sort products based on months where they can be purchased.
I'll have it in stock every year for specific months.

I want to mark each month 1 - 12.

To select the months I want to use, I'd type something like Select 1,2,11.
But I also have other products in the same table that uses other dates.

I.E month 1,5,7. I want to avoid using year and date format.

I currently have the table in this format.

```
Object | Month |
Peanut | 1,2,11|
Coconut| 4,5,8 |
```

That means that peanut will be extracted month 1 and 2 and 11.
Coconut will be extracted month 4, 5 and 8.

I've tried to select the month as an ID, but then I can't have several ID's on one product.

I've considered VarChar, but I'm not sure how I would get it to work, and if it would be slow.

I'm using HeidiSQL, with mySQL. Is there any alternative SQL's that would work?

Comment: @Zeedarn, is there a reason you want to avoid storing dates as dates? Doing so can lead to the data not acting how you think it should.

Comment: @Nathan Do you have a way to mark dates, from year 0 to date 9999? Like, only the specific months? I find it quite hard to mark several months in only one table on one ID

Comment: @Zeedarn, yes. As has been pointed out normalizing the data will help do that. If you will edit your question for help normalizing your data, I will add an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, but is not the best way. normalisation is your friend.

```
SELECT `Object` , `MONTH`
FROM mytable
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET("1",`MONTH`)
OR
  FIND_IN_SET("2",`MONTH`)
OR
  FIND_IN_SET("11",`MONTH`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your objects in a normalized format. The uniqueness of your record will be the object and the month it is to be extracted. Being comfortable with this set up will require a little practice, especially learning to work with dates (See [MySQL documentation on DATE types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html)). See the updated table below:

```
|Object   | Date     |
|-------- | -------- |
|Peanut   | 01-JAN-15|
|Peanut   | 01-FEB-15|
|Peanut   | 01-NOV-15|
|Coconut  | 01-APR-15|
|Coconut  | 01-MAY-15|
|Coconut  | 01-AUG-15|
```

Please note that a date data type is a piece of information that includes information on:

- century
- year
- month
- day
- hour
- minute
- second

The column is only displaying in a dd-MON-yy format. Now you will be able to write `SQL` statements which aggregate data more efficiently. A select statement limited to `JAN, FEB, NOV` with the `MONTH()` function would look as follows:

```
select object, date, month(date)
from myTable
where month(date) in (01, 02, 11);
```

Having the date stored as a date will allow you to use date and time functions. To learn more about date and time functions check out the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a row containing a list of months, try storing one row per month:

```
product | month |
Peanut | 1 |
Peanut | 2 |
Peanut | 11 |
Coconut| 4 |
Coconut| 5 |
Coconut| 8 |

-- What products are available in November?
SELECT product FROM product_month_available WHERE month=11;
```

Notes:

- Make both columns the key, or add a unique constraint on both
  columns, so that you don't have duplicate rows.
- `product_month_available.product` would typically be a FK to a `product` table containing the list of valid products, and possibly
  other data about each one.
- You can also add a constraint to ensure
  `product_month_available.month` is a valid month (1-12).